# Centering an ImageView in FullScreen mode

Tags: android, android-layout

I am simply trying to center an ImageView in a FullScreen app. I've read several posts on this site on people asking what seems like same question, and I've tried everything I've read, but I can't seem to get it to center.

Here is my code for the layout. I realize there might be some overkill here to get the centering, as a result of trying various other posts. This code puts the image on the top left part of the screen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/image"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:adjustViewBounds="true"
       android:background="@android:color/black"
       android:contentDescription="@string/descImage"
       android:cropToPadding="false"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
```

Here is my full screen code in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:theme="@style/Theme.FullScreen">
```

Theme.FullScreen is defined as

```
<style name="Theme.FullScreen" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works find on my galaxy nexus w/ 4.2 (I just changed width & height of image view as wrap_content and remove unnecessary & meaningless attributes.)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#000000">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and for theme...

```
<style name="Theme.FullScreen" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work. I'm curious to know what the new parent for the theme changes with respect to the centering.

Comment: No specific reason. But, when we extends the theme we don't need '@' and if you using Holo theme, there is already FullScreen theme, so I think it's good to use just prepared one.

Answer (score 0):

That seems very excessive for what you're trying to do. Try this?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descImage"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I tried exactly as you specified and wasn't able to get any difference. I'm willing to try anything just to get the image in the center... layout change, theme change...

Comment: Is the the full layout you are using for your activity?

Comment: Yes, that is everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `fill_parent` for the size, the entire view will not be centered in the parent, because it is the size of the parent.

If you change the size to `wrap_content`, the bounding box of the view will change, and that will be centered inside of the parent.

You could also use the `android:scaleType` property for the `imageView` specifying how the image resource itself should be layed out inside of the view.

The default `scaleType` will cause the resource image to appear in the top left corner of the ImageView, if the bouding box is larger then the actual image itself.

You can also use the `android:adjustViewBounds` property to have the OS automatically resize the bounding box for you, based on the image resource.

Comment: Unfortunately these suggestions didn't work... is there anything external to what I've shown that could be the culprit? I'm modifying someone else's code, so is it possible that there is setting somewhere else that overrides anything I've done?

Answer (score 0):

Use scaleType="fitCenter" on the ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

`fill_parent` has been replaced with `match_parent` in later Android versions and I've using an SVG drawable resource, so I had to modify the answers above slightly.

This is what worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.MyActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_drawable" />
</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```